# Однородные предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, и, учебное-задание

**Чуть тучка закроет солнце, лес сразу становится угрюмый(,) и погода кажется пасмурной.**

Объясните, пожалуйста, вторую запятую.
Действует ли здесь правило: если есть общее придаточное и одиночный союз "и" между однородными предложениями, то запятая не ставится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чуть тучка закроет солнце, лес **сразу** становится угрюмый, и погода кажется пасмурной"

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

2) Общей может быть придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения: Уже совсем рассвело и народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату (Л. Т.); Когда он вернулся в залу, сердце его билось и руки дрожали так заметно… (Ч.);

Но: Когда Каштанка проснулась, было уже светло, и с улицы доносился шум, какой бывает только днём (Ч.) — **придаточная часть относится только к первому простому предложению**, а связь его со вторым слабее, на что указывает различный вид глаголов-сказуемых этих предложений.

В заданном предложении запятая ставится в соответствии с замечанием **о более слабой связи последнего предложения с придаточной частью.** Это видно по смыслу, а также по временному наречию ***сразу***: лес сразу становится угрюмый, а потом (пока солнце не выглянет) погода кажется пасмурной.

Comment: Наверно, не "потом", а **потому** (если я правильно понимаю).

Comment: Я имела в виду именно разную протяженность во времени, а не причину: лес сразу делается пасмурным, как только туча закроет солнце, и затем некоторое время, пока солнца нет, погода кажется пасмурной.

Comment: @Sharon А где там "потом"? Никакого "потом" нет. Это вы придумали. Как это: солнце скрылось, лес *сразу* стал угрюмым, а погода только *потом* показалась пасмурной? Так не бывает. Да и вид у глаголов-сказуемых одинаковый.

Comment: @Niemand По контексту книги имеется в виду следующее. Когда небольшая тучка на время закрывает солнце, то на открытой местности погода по-прежнему ощущается погожей, а в лесу сразу покажется, что день мрачный и пасмурный. Объяснение Sharon верно по сути (про ослабление связи), и даже если к нему можно придраться по формальным признакам, это всё равно не будет означать, что запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Запятой быть не должно: чистое общее придаточное при двух главных. Откуда текст?

Comment: Текст из книги В. Арсеньева "По Уссурийскому краю". В электронном издании стоит запятая. Думаю, в оригинале тоже стоит.

Comment: Корректоры, они такие корректоры... Да и в стародавние времена правила были другие. Так что на это ссылаться нельзя.

Comment: А зачем было спрашивать, раз всё равно нельзя ссылаться, поскольку не совпало с Вашим решением? :) Если бы в предложении не было слов "сразу" и "кажется", но при этом стояла запятая, я бы согласился с Вами по поводу горе-корректоров (но не про стародавние времена — не совсем понял, какое в данном случае правило изменилось).

Comment: Вряд ли было правило об общих второстепенных членах, общих главных и придаточных и т.п. Впрочем, не знаю. А слова "кажется" и "сразу" на структуру фразы влияют чуть меньше, чем никак. Так что тут налицо подгонка под ответ: увидели в тексте запятую и стали ее "обосновывать".